# Am I using this transistor improperly?

Tags: arduino, transistors, electromagnetic

I've prototyped the circuit below on a normal breadboard and it works as desired. However, I'm very new to electronics and what to make sure I'm not abusing my transistor.

I'm using the piezo element to detect a certain knock pattern. If the correct pattern is detected, it disables the electomagnetic lock (allowing the door to be opened).

When my microcontroller is booted, it immediately sends a HIGH signal to the transistor (thus activating the electromagnetic lock) and keeps it there until the door is successfully unlocked. After a few seconds of being unlocked, it then reactivates the lock. As a result, it's going to be "on" 99% of it's lifetime. After letting this run for several hours, my transistor is a little hot to the touch.

My question is this:  Is it OK to use the transistor this way (i.e. in an "always on/open" state)? Or is this a bad idea and I should take a different approach?

[image]

Comment: That seems like a poorly designed locking mechanism if it needs to be constantly powered to stay locked. Did you find it on a movie set ... ?

Comment: I mean, it seems to make sense that an electromagnet would require power to be active. This is the lock: http://www.seco-larm.com/E-941SA-600

Comment: His point is that a better design might be to _unlock_ with the solenoid. That would only require intermittent operation.

Comment: I see. I should mention that this is more of a fun/learning project and that the lock will only be securing the door to my basement workshop. I'm not trying to secure Fort Knox, and I'd prefer fail-insecure. I appreciate the advice though. But regarding the usage of the transistor, am I doing anything wrong or unsafe?

Comment: Depends on safety requirements. On the majority of sites I am on most doors are Fail Safe (Power to Lock), especially on fire doors as this allows EDRU/EBG emergency door release. Fail Secure (Power to Open) is extremely unsafe as there is no way to guarantee control panels or cabling can supply power in a fire or other disaster, breaking power is much easier. Certain situations obviously do call for Fail Secure but it's a design issue, safety vs security.  Also consider fitting a diode or snubber for back EMF across your lock if required, some do have one built in.

Comment: Can you tell us the voltage across the transistor (measure with a volt meter from collector to emitter). Also, what is the power source for the lock? 12V or 24V? According to the lock information, it can be either 500 mA at 12V or 250 mA at 24V. So we need to know which one it is to calculate the power dissipation in the transistor.

Comment: Provide a proper schematic, instead of that Fritzing rubbish.

Comment: I agree with @LeonHeller Don't use Fritzing. It's difficult to follow, looks crappy, and is incredibly unprofessional. Just post a schematic of your setup.

Comment: Fritzing can also provide schematics from the "cartoons."  So, have Fritzing show you the schematic and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely ok to have transistor always on. There's nothing wrong with that. However, you must look at power dissipation. Transistor is able to dissipate only certain amount of heat. This amount is specified in datasheet. It depends on amount of passing current, voltage across colector-emitter and that depends on base current. If you dissipate too much heat, transistor gets hot, and you will need to use heatsink.
Look at the voltage across colector-emitter. If it is not close to 2V, than you probably need to increase voltage on base (or use lower resistor). Otherwise you need heatsink.
**UPDATE:**
I recommend to use MOSFET instead of TIP120 which is NPN Darlington. MOSFET dissipates much less heat, it is much better for power switching.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you! I'll do some reading up on what a MOSFET is (very new to all of this). My only other idea was to use a normally closed relay for the electromagnet circuit (then using the 5v to open it when access is granted)

Comment: TIP120 is pretty much unkillable in hobby electronics except if you abuse it a lot and by a lot I mean push obscene amount power in it.